# c++ Why to use reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I am a C++ newbie and I am working on a program that simulates a phonebook. Now, for the insert operation, function is defined as follows:

```
void PhoneBook::insert(const string& name, const string& number)
```

But it still works and inserts the contact as well if I remove the reference symbols. So, I am a little confused here, why do I need them?

```
void PhoneBook::insert(const string name, const string number)
```

Comment: In order to avoid unnecessary string copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void PhoneBook::insert(const string name, const string number)`

Here you are constructing new strings with copy of all data. This is heavy operation.

`void PhoneBook::insert(const string& name, const string& number)`

Here you are passing reference to string (address of string), size of which is usually 4 or 8 bytes, based on platform, which is very light operation.

Also, when you pass reference, you are allowed to interact with object, which you are passed to function.

Rule of thumb - always pass by const reference, if variable is bigger than 8 bytes and you dont require explicit copy of object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on the given duplicate link.

Comment: This fails to address the fundamental semantic difference between referencing a foreign object and creating a new copy to hold onto. Optimization concerns, which seem to be all the craze with reference parameters, come way later down the line.